# Multiple Images Upload React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some weird issue going on here, which works in Mozilla Firefox, but doesn't work with Google Chrome nor Brave Browser.

Basically I am trying to upload images and displaying uploaded images at bottom.

Problem is, if I upload a image and delete the selected image and try to reupload same image again, it doesn't upload nor display the image in the preview section.

Here's my code so far :

```
const selectImages = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const files = [...e.target.files];
    // const files = e.target.files;
    console.log(files)
    let newImages = [...images, ...files];

    console.log('total images :' , newImages )
    if (newImages?.length > 5) {
      newImages = newImages.slice(0, 5);
    }

    const newImagePreviews = newImages.map((file, index) => {
      // const uniqueKey = Date.now() + index;
      return {
        id: index,
        name: file.name,
        url: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      };
    });

    setImages(newImages);
    setImagePreviews(newImagePreviews);
  };

 
  const deleteImage = (index) => {
    const updatedImages = [...images];
    const updatedPreviews = [...imagePreviews];
  
    updatedImages.splice(index, 1); 
    updatedPreviews.splice(index, 1); 
  
    // const updatedImages = images.filter((image) => image.id !== id);
    // const updatedPreviews = imagePreviews.filter((image) => image.id !== id);
    console.log('updatedImages : ',updatedImages)
    setImages(updatedImages);
    setImagePreviews(updatedPreviews);
  };
<input
                  type="file"
                  accept="image/*"
                  multiple
                  id="imageUpload"
                  style={{ display: 'none' }}
                  onChange={selectImages}
                />

                <div className="image-previews">
                  {imagePreviews.map((image, index) => {
                    return (
                      <div className="image" key={index}>
                        <img src={image.url} />
                        <p className="file-name">{image.name}</p>
                        <div className="delete">
                          <button
                            onClick={() => deleteImage(index)}
                          >{t('DELETE')}</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )
                  })}
                </div>
```

I don't see any logs of selected files: `console.log(files)` when I try to reupload deleted image again (aka reupload same image which was deleted earlier).

Can anyone help me with this about what the situation is here?

This code works perfectly for Mozilla Firefox!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete an image and try to reupload the same image, it doesn't work in Chrome or Brave browsers.

The `input` element is not resetting its value when you delete an image, so when you try to select the same file again, it doesn't trigger the `onChange` event.

So you can try adding an `onClick` event handler to your `input` element that clears its value before selecting a file. For example:

```
<input
  type="file"
  accept="image/*"
  multiple
  id="imageUpload"
  style={{ display: "none" }}
  onChange={selectImages}
  onClick={(e) => (e.target.value = "")}
/>
```

You can add the `onClick` handler to your `input` element even if you hide it from users.
The `onClick` handler will be triggered when the user clicks on the `button` or `label` that is associated with the `input` element.

Comment: This worked ! thanks for the explaination and solution @Victor L

Comment: I'm glad that you solve the problem. @ksd030687d